# Não mostrar elemento que tenham um determinado valor

Tags: mysql

Em MySQL tenho uma tabela chamada **usuario** onde são armazenados todos os usuários do site:

```
ID | NOME
 1 | bla
 2 | ble
 3 | bli
 4 | blo
```

E uma tabela chamada **usuario_gerenciamento**, onde estão campos relacionados ao gerenciamento desses usuários:

```
USUARIO_ID | CREDENCIAL_ID
    1      |     1
    2      |     1
    2      |     2
    3      |     1
    4      |     1
    4      |     2
```

*(as tabelas são bem mais complexas, simplifiquei para focar na minha dúvida)*

O que não estou conseguindo fazer é dar uma select nos usuários, e NÃO mostrar os usuários que tenha a CREDENCIAL_ID = 2, meu código até agora:

```
SELECT usuario.id AS usuarioId FROM usuario
LEFT JOIN usuario_gerenciamento ON usuario.id = usuario_gerenciamento.usuario_id
WHERE usuario_gerenciamento.credencial_id <> 2
```

Mas ele mostra todos os usuários, eu até entendo que isso ocorre pois os usuários tem outras credenciais além da 2, mas como fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você terá que fazer com `sub-select`:

```
SELECT usuario.id AS usuarioId
FROM usuario
LEFT JOIN usuario_gerenciamento ON usuario.id = usuario_gerenciamento.usuario_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM usuario_gerenciamento
    WHERE usuario_gerenciamento.usuario_id = usuario.id
        AND usuario_gerenciamento.credencial_id = 2 
);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT usuario.id AS usuarioId
FROM usuario
LEFT JOIN usuario_gerenciamento ON usuario.id = usuario_gerenciamento.usuario_id
WHERE usuario.id NOT IN 
(SELECT usuario_id FROM usuario_gerenciamento WHERE credencial_id = 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Para isso será necessário usar uma sub-query, desta forma:

```
SELECT usuario.id 
FROM usuario 
WHERE usuario.id in (
    SELECT usuario_id FROM usuario_gerenciamento
    WHERE usuario_gerenciamento.credencial_id = 2 
);
```

A sub-query vai trazer somente os usuários com a credencial 2.

Para trazer todos aqueles que não possuem a credencial 2, você pode usar o NOT IN como critério da consulta:

```
SELECT usuario.id 
FROM usuario 
WHERE usuario.id not in (
    SELECT usuario_id FROM usuario_gerenciamento
    WHERE usuario_gerenciamento.credencial_id = 2 
);
```

Pode ser lido assim:

> Traga os usuários que NÃO estejam no grupo de usuários com a credencial IGUAL à 2.

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e3251/5)